# Excel - VBA: Code is generating unexpected numbers (0)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck on this, I don't understand why the code adds those extra zeros in column D; What am I doing wrong?

Code: https://pastebin.com/ccpqPJdz

```
last = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Insert 3 columns on left. Add information in Row 1, add data in column D.
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("E:E").Copy Destination:=Columns("C:C")
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("D2:D2" & last).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[6]"
Columns("D").Copy
Columns("D").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D1") = Time
Range("D1").NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss"
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: `Range("D2:D2" & last)` is the cause.  If last = say 3 that will reference `D2:D23`

Comment: Aside from that you should read [how to avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the `Selection` object. It's created as a medium of communication between the user and VBA via the screen. VBA has direct access to the Excel workbook and therefore doesn't need it. Please try this code.

```
Private Sub InsertThreeColumns()

    Dim Rl          As Long         ' last used row
    Dim Rng         As Range

    With Worksheets("NewTest")      ' change to suit
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns(2).Copy
        .Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

        .Columns(5).EntireColumn.Delete
        On Error Resume Next
        ' next line will cause a crash if there are no blanks
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(Rl, "D")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        If Err = 0 Then
            Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[6]"
            Rng.Copy
            Rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        With .Cells(1, "D")
            .Value = Time
            .NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The extra zeroes that troubled you were caused by the method of defining the range where you wanted the formula to supply cell content. In your code that range is a derivative of a `Selection`. In the above code it's defined by starting cell and end cell. The result should be the same. It isn't because the route via the `Selection` object is circuitous and difficult to follow.